# uitableview cell back ground colour issue on scroll

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have my uitable view cell for row like this:

```
if (!cell) {
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenOrdersCell" bundle:nil];
    cell = (OpenOrdersCell *)controller.view;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0f/255.0f green:238.0f/255.0f blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

}...
```

this runs fine without any issue, and code remains statle even on scroll up and down many times.
Now in didSelect row delegate method i want to change background color of row.I am successfull in this also.But as soon as i scroll below below cell back ground colour become selected colour.

this is the code in didSelect:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
OpenOrdersCell *cell = (OpenOrdersCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"row is %d section is %d cell.orderIdLabel.text is %@",indexPath.row, indexPath.section, cell.orderIdLabel.text);
[self reStructureCellForIndexPath:indexPath andCell:cell];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

and this is restructure:

```
if ([cell viewWithTag:TAG_EXPANDED_CELL_VIEW]) {


    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0f/255.0f green:238.0f/255.0f blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];//default bg

    return;
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:195.0f/255.0f green:199.0f/255.0f blue:202.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];//selected bg
```

[the expanded view with selected id 166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdOTH.png)

[image]

[as i scroll below you can see cell with if 148 becomes selected with selected back ground color ?? this is the issue]

[image]

Comment: Is possible that you dequeue cell and not change background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selected cell is being reused and you are not reseting the background colour...

```
if (!cell) {
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenOrdersCell" bundle:nil];
    cell = (OpenOrdersCell *)controller.view;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0f/255.0f green:238.0f/255.0f blue  :238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

}...
```

In here you need to determine if the cell is the selected one and set the background accordingly...

```
if (!cell) {
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenOrdersCell" bundle:nil];
    cell = (OpenOrdersCell *)controller.view;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

}...

//

if(indexPath.Row == savedSelectedRow) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:195.0f/255.0f green:199.0f/255.0f blue:202.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];//selected bg
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:238.0f/255.0f green:238.0f/255.0f blue  :238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

In your `didSelect` you can then store the `indexPath.Row` in a variable called `savedSelectedRow` for future checking